# SQL Query Date Format Two Columns

Tags: php, mysql, sql, date

I have two columns (Date and Time) in database that I would like to get from SQL query with specific date format.  It can be two values from sql query or one. Here are the details.

Display Format:

Sunday 03/31/2013 12:13:27 AM

Database Columns:

1. EndDate (Date yyyy-mm-dd)
2. EndTime (Time hh:mm:ss)

Comment: This question does not show any research effort. It is important to **do your homework**. Tell us what you found and ***why*** it didn't meet your needs. This demonstrates that you've taken the time to try to help yourself, it saves us from reiterating obvious answers, and most of all it helps you get a more specific and relevant answer. [FAQ](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/how-to-ask).

Comment: Are you trying to do this in PHP or MySQL?  What have you tried so far to achieve this?

Comment: I need a sql query that properly formats date from two columns in database. Example: date_format(a.EndDate, '%W %m/%d/%Y %r')

Comment: What exactly you need? To Format `SQL Query` you can use `DATE_FORMAT()` https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/date-and-time-functions.html#function_date-format

Comment: Do your homework before asking. This answer is just a google search away. Check this article: http://whathaveyoutried.com

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is what you need:

```
DATE_FORMAT(CONCAT(EndDate, EndTime), '%W %m/%d/%Y %r')
```

Answer (score 0):

The `date_format()` function gives you everything you need.

**Example.** Let's say you have columns `aDate` and `aTime` in your table, and you need to show the date like 'dd-mm-yyyy' and the time like 'hh:mm'. So:

```
select
    date_format(aDate, '%d-$m-%Y'), date_format(aTime, '%H:%i')
from myTable;
```

Check the reference manual (Chapter 12 - Functions and operators for MySQL 5.5)

If you need to concatenate the results, then:

```
select
    concat(date_format(aDate, '%d-$m-%Y'), ' ', date_format(aTime, '%H:%i'))
from myTable;
```

Answer (score 0):

This seems to work for me:

```
select date_format(concat(enddate,' ',endtime),'%W %m/%d/%Y %r')
from yourtable
```

[SQL Fiddle Demo](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/572e7/1)

Good documentation for date_format: https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/date-and-time-functions.html#function_date-format